# how to implement a re-callable future in provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

In my app, in a certain screen, there are **3 `ToggleButtons`**, which represent **3 types of products**, and a **list of products** of that category which will be **given by an API call** to a provider class. the list can be **viewed in 2 ways**, each a seperate widget. note this is a simplification as there is at least 2 widget files between the screen widget and the togglebuttons widget or the listitem widget files.

What i want to achieve is that **on first load**, **the API is called** (a future) to provide a list of products of the 1st category, which is displayed by default, and **when a user clicks** on the ToggleButton of the 2nd or 3rd categories, **a new API call is made** and the **list is rebuilt** with the new data. ***What would be the correct provider to use in this case?***

I have tried using a `FutureProvider`, but it didn't work as it would either not build the list at all, or rebuild it constantly. `StreamProvider` doesn't seem to work either as it's builder is only run once.

Answer (score 0):

NotifyListeners is the easiest and simplest way to work with the Provider where we just need to call the notifyListeners() method to tell the “listeners” to rebuild and get the new value.

You can just call notifyListeners() when you click on the toggle button.

Note you can only notifyListener() in the class which extends ChangeNotifer.
So in that class create a function which will do your 2nd category API and write changeNotifier in it.

```
class CreditCardViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
   
   changeCategory(String category) {
    //API Call for the new category
     response = ApiData;
    notifyListeners();
   }
   
   getAPIData(){
   
   return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best provider in the end was the ***changeNotifierProvider***.
I initialize the list of items to an **empty list at first**, and in the provider's **constructor** I call a **Future**, but I **don't await it**. the **Future calls the api** and **sets the list** to be the incoming data, **then calls notifyListeners()**. The list, now changed, displays the new data.